# Filter the dataframe till the last occurence of a condition being met (pyspark)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a predictions column and a labels (binary) column. The dataset has around 99% 1s and 1% 0s in the labels column. The predictions column is not a conclusive determinant of the labels column but a good correlation holds (If you sort the data by predictions and bucket it into deciles then the mean of labels in each decile would go up).

Now, I want to sort the dataframe by predictions and subset it till the cumulative mean of the labels is below a threshold.

The issue is that there would be a 1 in the labels column where the threshold would be breached and then there would be a bunch of 0s and hence the cumulative mean could fall below the threshold again. I want all these rows to be selected in the final subset as well

I want to subset the DataFrame (post sorting it by predictions) till the last time the mean of the labels is below the threshold

example (running mean columns won't be there):

```
    preds   labels  running_mean
0   0.05    1   1.000000
1   0.10    0   0.500000
2   0.15    0   0.333333
3   0.20    0   0.250000
4   0.25    1   0.400000
5   0.30    0   0.333333
6   0.35    0   0.285714
7   0.40    1   0.375000
8   0.45    1   0.444444
9   0.50    1   0.500000
10  0.55    1   0.545455
11  0.60    1   0.583333
12  0.65    1   0.615385
13  0.70    1   0.642857
14  0.75    0   0.600000
15  0.80    1   0.625000
16  0.85    1   0.647059
17  0.90    1   0.666667
18  0.95    1   0.684211
```

In the above dataframe say the threshold is 0.63 then I want to select the first 16 rows (up to and including row indexed 15)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

- ignore the first row
- find the rows that the running_mean exceeds the threshold
- find the first place that the threshold reached
- filter the rows

```
data = [
    (0.05, 1),
    (0.10, 0),
    (0.15, 0),
    (0.20, 0),
    (0.25, 1),
    (0.30, 0),
    (0.35, 0),
    (0.40, 1),
    (0.45, 1),
    (0.50, 1),
    (0.55, 1),
    (0.60, 1),
    (0.65, 1),
    (0.70, 1),
    (0.75, 0),
    (0.80, 1),
    (0.85, 1),
    (0.90, 1),
    (0.95, 1)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['preds', 'labels'])

cutoff = 0.63
w = Window.orderBy('preds')

df.withColumn('running_mean', f.avg('labels').over(w)) \
  .withColumn('temp', f.when(f.lead('running_mean').over(w) <= f.lit(cutoff), 0).otherwise(1)) \
  .withColumn('temp', f.sum('temp').over(w)) \
  .filter(f.col('temp') == 0) \
  .show(truncate=False)

+-----+------+------------------+----+
|preds|labels|running_mean      |temp|
+-----+------+------------------+----+
|0.05 |1     |1.0               |0   |
|0.1  |0     |0.5               |0   |
|0.15 |0     |0.3333333333333333|0   |
|0.2  |0     |0.25              |0   |
|0.25 |1     |0.4               |0   |
|0.3  |0     |0.3333333333333333|0   |
|0.35 |0     |0.2857142857142857|0   |
|0.4  |1     |0.375             |0   |
|0.45 |1     |0.4444444444444444|0   |
|0.5  |1     |0.5               |0   |
|0.55 |1     |0.5454545454545454|0   |
|0.6  |1     |0.5833333333333334|0   |
+-----+------+------------------+----+
```